# Rails 3: wrapping ActiveRecord operations and external credit card in a single transaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, transactions, activemerchant

I'm using ActiveMerchant to process a credit card transaction which may succeed or fail, which is part of a bigger transaction involving some internal accounting using ActiveRecord processing.  I am not clear on how to roll back the entire transaction if a part fails.

I have a Payment model, and a Points model -- a user's points are converted to dollars to be used to reduce their payment.  So I need to do these things:

- Several validations relating to amount and points
- Save points transactions: Debit user account, credit internal account
- Charge credit card the amount of payment less value from points
- Save this payment data
- Save the credit card transaction result (whether it succeeds or fails)
- Then if everything works, send an email to the user

I see how [ActiveRecord::Transactions](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html) work, and assume I can use the `after_commit` (and `after_rollback`) callbacks to handle stuff like emailing the user.

But how do I make a failed credit card transaction cause the same rollback that a failed AR `save` would cause?  Is it as easy as calling `raise ActiveRecord::Rollback` if my non-AR transaction fails?  There's a section in the doc linked above that makes me nervous about this (relating to transactions not working across multiple database connections).

Rails 3.2.5, MySQL 5.1 (InnoDB), Ruby 1.9.3

Comment: Your ActiveMerchant calls are to an external server so it will not affect your ActiveRecord transactions. Feel free to raise `ActiveRecord::Rollback`.

Comment: @TanzeebKhalili -- move this to an answer and I'll mark it answered -- it's all done and works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ActiveMerchant calls are to an external server so it will not affect your ActiveRecord transactions. Feel free to raise `ActiveRecord::Rollback`.